# Find the one non-repeating element in array?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, time-complexity

I have an array of `n` elements in which only one element is not repeated, else all the other numbers are repeated >1 times. And there is no limit on the range of the numbers in the array.

Some solutions are:

- **Making use of hash,** but that would result in linear time complexity but very poor space complexity
- **Sorting the list** using MergeSort `O(nlogn)` and then finding the element which doesn't repeat

Is there a better solution?

Comment: Hash tables don't actually take all that much space : `O(n)`.  If the array is so large that you must do it in-place, then you'll probably want to do it with an external sort.

Comment: A hash's space-complexity is at most `O(n)` (there may be a `C > x`, for some smallish `x`, depending on implementation, though). I like the "sort first approach".

Comment: Yes, but merge-sort (inplace) has space complexity zero.

Comment: @Thilo Just counter-acting to the "very poor space complexity" ;)

Comment: @bdares In-place hashing couldn't be implemented because there's no upper bound on the range of numbers in the array.

Comment: @Luv it doesn't matter what the range of the numbers are.  Good hashing algorithms don't care what the range is, just the number of unique elements.  Think of the primitive hash, modulo by your storage space.  It doesn't matter how big the number is, it'll fit into your table.  It won't be in-place because it takes extra storage space proportional to `n`, but it won't be very large.

Comment: If you could limit it from >=2 to equal 2 (or at least a multiple of 2), the solution would be easy: just xor all numbers together.

Comment: @bdares the range of numbers does matter because it rules out things like count-sort which is O(n).

Answer (score 1):

One general approach is to implement a bucketing technique (of which hashing is such a technique) to distribute the elements into different "buckets" using their identity (say index) and then find the bucket with the smallest size (1 in your case). This problem, I believe, is also known as the minority element problem. There will be as many buckets as there are unique elements in your set.

Doing this by hashing is problematic because of collisions and how your algorithm might handle that. Certain associative array approaches such as tries and extendable hashing don't seem to apply as they are better suited to strings.

One application of the above is to the [Union-Find data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure). Your sets will be the buckets and you'll need to call MakeSet() and Find() for each element in your array for a cost of  $O(\alpha(n))$ per call, where $\alpha(n)$ is the extremely slow-growing inverse Ackermann function. You can think of it as being effectively a constant.

You'll have to do Union when an element already exist. With some changes to keep track of the set with minimum cardinality, this solution should work. The time complexity of this solution is $O(n\alpha(n))$.

Your problem also appears to be loosely related to the [Element Uniqueness problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Element_distinctness_problem).

Answer (score 1):

Try a multi-pass scanning if you have strict space limitation.

Say the input has n elements and you can only hold m elements in your memory. If you use a hash-table approach, in the worst case you need to handle n/2 unique numbers so you want m>n/2. In case you don't have that big m, you can partition n elements to k=(max(input)-min(input))/(2m) groups, and go ahead scan the n input elements k times (in the worst case):

1st run: you only hash-get/put/mark/whatever elements with value < min(input)+m*2; because in the range (min(input), min(input)+m*2) there are at most m unique elements and you can handle that. If you are lucky you already find the unique one, otherwise continue.

2nd run: only operate on elements with value in range (min(input)+m*2, min(input)+m*4), and
so on, so forth

In this way, you compromise the time complexity to a O(kn), but you get a space complexity bound of O(m)

Answer (score 1):

Two ideas come to my mind:

- A [smoothsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothsort) may be a better alternative than the cited mergesort for your needs given it's O(1) in memory usage, O(nlogn) in the worst case as the merge sort but O(n) in the best case;
- Based on the (reverse) idea of the [splay tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splay_tree), you could make a type of tree that would 
  push the leafs toward the bottom once they are used (instead of upward as in the splay tree). This would still give you a O(nlogn) implantation of the sort, but the advantage would be the O(1) step of finding the unique element, it would be the root. The sorting algorithm is the sum of O(nlogn) + O(n) and this algorithm would be O(nlogn) + O(1)

Otherwise, as you stated, using a hash based solution (like hash-implemented set) would result in a O(n) algorithm (O(n) to insert and add a counting reference to it and O(n) to traverse your set to find the unique element) but you seemed to dislike the memory usage, though I don't know why. Memory is cheap, these days...